# Issue with Cell value of different column after sorting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel with multiple rows. for example in cell A2 I have formula (=B3). The problem is if I sort the table. After sorting the row 3 moves to different row (example 5) but the formula remains the same = (=B3).

Is there a way so that even if I sort the table the formula gets the value from the proper cell in row?

this maybe simple but could not figure out. hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the sheet name. For example instead of "=B3" use "=Sheet1!B3", then the formula will not change after sorting.